# Azure SQL Database - Modify cost threshold for parallelism

Tags: sql-server, azure-sql-database, azure-sql-server

I attempted to update the value of `cost threshold for parallelism` but since my database is an Azure SQL database I can't run the command:

```
EXEC sp_configure 'cost threshold for parallelism', 40 ;
GO
RECONFIGURE
```

due to an error of "*Could not find stored procedure 'sp_configure'.*"

Is it possible to update this setting in Azure SQL database?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You cannot change the `cost threshold for parallelism` for the Azure SQL Database PaaS service.

You can only change the `MAXDOP` at the query and database levels. Details [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/configure-max-degree-of-parallelism).

Ref:

- [Azure SQL Database and Cost Threshold for Parallelism](https://blobeater.blog/2018/03/16/azure-sql-database-and-cost-threshold-for-parallelism/) by Blobeater
- [Change the setting "Cost Threshold For Parallelism"](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/ef148d2a-2262-410f-b413-4f4cefcd3291/change-the-setting-quotcost-threshold-for-parallelismquot?forum=ssdsgetstarted)